# How can we implement Jeff Eaton's custom tags strategy in Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, xml, content-management-system, preprocessor

I distinctly recognise the problem described in Jeff Eaton's article [The Battle for the Body Field](http://alistapart.com/article/battle-for-the-body-field) on A List Apart. That of handing clients a CMS that strikes a balance between conceptual simplicity in editing content, and flexibility in the flow and structure of that content. Whilst generating clean, forward-compatible code and responsive layouts.

I'm now convinced that some sort of custom tags are the solution to this problem. Even if they are wrapped in a WYSIWYG editor.

I'd like to keep preprocessing server-side until web-components are more widely, natively supported. And I favour Ruby/Rails for development.

So what libraries are available that would help with preprocessing and expanding custom XML or HTML tags in this way?

XSLT seems too limited. And [Radius](https://github.com/jlong/radius) is perhaps a contender, though it doesn't appear to still be in active development.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to favour markdown because it's extensible and acts as a subgroup of HTML. In Ruby, the main contenders are [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) and [kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/). There are others, but I have not used them.

Redcarpet is mature and solid. It is also highly performant and extensible. You can define your own custom tags and syntax. It allows you to pre-process and post-process content.

It has disadvantages, though. Since it adheres to the markdown standard it can be limiting. I wrote my own `figure` tag syntax, and found that it was being inserted between paragraph tags,  leading to invalid HTML. This is not its own fault. It's how markdown works.

```
!![figure caption](image_url "img alt text")
```

An alternative is [kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/), which is written with flexibility in mind. It allows full customisation of your syntax.